# Slider going too far

Tags: jquery

I am making a slider for a website and I have almost everything done except the slider goes one further then I need. Can anyone tell me why? I need `left` to hide after it has been clicked twice but instead it hides after I click it 3 times.

here is a link to the site its on http://alanvitek.com/dev

here is the jquery

```
jQuery(function($){
    var sec = $('.portfolioWide'), secwidth = sec.width(), unit = 1040;

    $(".button-next").click(function() {
        var left = sec.css('left');
        left = Math.abs(parseInt(left.substring(0, left.length - 2)))
        if(left + unit >= secwidth){
            $(this).hide()
        }

        sec.animate({left: "-=" + unit }, "slow");
        $(".button-back").show();
    });
```

Comment: @Praveen i added the link to the site

Comment: Three slides are there right.. then y do u want to hide once u clicked next for one time?

Comment: @Praveen i want it to hide when i click it twice, it hides once i click it 3 times. the first one with the fish counts as a slide.

Comment: make it so easy with array concept... pass your div id in arrays. and check the condition eith its length and display:none it

Comment: @Praveen code please lol